# Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found PHP in Win Server 2008 R2

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

I have installed all the required libraries like

```
[COM_DOT_NET]
     extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

and restarted IIS and still cannot make it to work? Any clues as I am keep getting that error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that it is enabled in IIS

IIS Manager -> PHP Manager -> PHP Extensions -> Enable or Disable Extensions

Also make sure that the dll file is in the ext folder of your php installation

Comment: but you enable them by inserting them into php.ini file. Yes paths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
add<br>
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll<br>
on php.ini
```